# Why present simple for a temporary state

Tags: present-tense

Many students are not going to school at the moment .They are practising and studying at in their houses . Their Teachers **send** them videos and activities  every day .

Why "send" is not present continuous as sending some videos is a temporary thing. I know that every day needs present but when school is back, teachers won't send videos anymore so continuous should do it too.

My mother is working at home so during the week she **talks** to people all the time

Same question why not present continuous for talk as it is a temporary state

https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Verb_tenses/Revision_of_tenses_kp166797os

Answer (score -2):

Original: "Many students are not going to school at the moment .They are practising and studying at in their houses . Their Teachers send them videos and activities every day ."

Better: "Many students are not going to school at the moment. They are practising and studying at home. Their Teachers send them videos and activities every day."

Best: "Many students are not going to school at the moment. They are practising and studying at home. Their Teachers **are sending** them videos and activities every day."

Using the present continuous because the previous sentence was present tense - "are practicing" ... suggesting they were and still are.

Both examples work perfectly to the native ear. It's a subtle thing, but tenses mostly need to be kept consistent else they can sound a bit off.

My mother is working at home, so, during the week she talks to people all the time.
My mother is working at home, so, during the week she is talking to people all the time.

Interchangeable with little emphasis on what is correct. In English the only detectable difference is that the first sentence sounds a little 'detached'. The second is a little more imminent, closer.

I would argue that past continuous is required for something you were doing all the time, especially if this was never specified to have stopped. To have specified it stopped occuring in the past it would make sense to use this:

Past Continuous:
My mother was working at home, so, during the week she was speaking to people all the time.

Present
My mother is working at home, so, during the week she speaks to people all the time.

To seperate the two sentences you would need to consider this:
My mother is working at home, so, last week she spoke to people all the time.

There we mixed the tenses. As a result the definite article 'the' changed to 'last'. This is because it wasn't just any week, it was specifically the last week.  She is still working but we are specific to the past last week. To the ear this sounds distinctive, you draw more attention to last week.
Both flows are kept even though a sentence apart. The emphasis is on whether this is happening in the past and has either stopped now or is continuing. And its probably just most important to keep the flow of tenses from one sentence to the next, rather than the nuance of what exact tense it is.

I don't think it matters that much, the way you used your full stops and wording of at home was more jarring.

Comment: Personally, I think your "best" version is actually the ***worst***. There's no real justification for even using the continuous verb form *once* in the cited text, and slavishly repeating it just makes the entire utterance verbosely clumsy. In similar contexts involving *Past **Perfect***, it's often "necessary" to use that verb form for the *first* clause, but drop back to Simple Past for all subsequent verbs even if they all refer to the same "past within the past" time frame. Imho, repeating complex verb forms is usually a bad idea *stylistically*, even if *logically* it seems "correct".

Comment: My "best": *Many students don't go to school at the moment. They practice and study at home. Their teachers send them videos and activities every day.*

Comment: why present simple for the first verb. Is it because  at the moment   means temporary but even if it is  for a long time